# Item highlight not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with a horizontal scroll bar that I made with RecyclerView,

**Hint:**

I use `SharedPreferences` in `onItemClick` interface to transfer the position of clicked item to the fragment where I set the adapter , then I use another interface to  transfer the clicked item position from the fragment to the activity where I set current item via `viewpager`.

***Current behavior:***

**Issue #1**

**when an item gets selected the background (highlight) color is not changing, it has to be clicked again to get the highlight color.**
[image]

**Issue #2**

**When an item is clicked the scroll state resets to 1**
[image]

**Question :**

**why is this happening? and how to fix it?**

***Expected behavior***

**when an item is clicked I want the following behavior (single item selection)**
[image]

**RecyclerView adapter class**

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder> {


        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(PlanetModel item);
        }

    private ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;


    SharedPreferences getPref1x1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int pos1x1 = getPref1x1.getInt("position",0);

    int isPlanetSelected=pos1x1;


    public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.episodeslist = episodeslist;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planet_row, parent,false);
        PlanetViewHolder vh=new PlanetViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
        tv.setText(episodeslist.get(position).getPlanetName());
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bg, 0, 0, 0);

        vh.bind(episodeslist.get(position), listener);



        if (episodeslist.get(position).isPlanetSelected()) {
            vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }else{
            vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        }



        //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.planetimage);
        //vh.text.setText(episodeslist.get(position).toString());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return episodeslist.size();
    }


    public class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        protected TextView text;
        public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        }
        public void bind(final PlanetModel item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getPosition();

                    int previousItem = isPlanetSelected;
                    isPlanetSelected = position;

                    notifyItemChanged(previousItem);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);




                    SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).apply ();



                     listener.onItemClick(item);
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + ((TextView) itemView).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SharedPreference` has a wrong-stored position value. To get the correct position within the `ViewHolder`, you need to use [`getBindingAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) instead of `getPosition`.

Also you should update the value of the `item` before using `listener.onItemClick(item);`

Also you need to toggle the value of the selection boolean on the object before using `notifyItemChanged()` in order to reflect the change.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();

        int previousItem = selectedPosition;
        selectedPosition = position;
        
        // Updating the selector boolean before notifying the changes to the adapter
        
        PlanetModel currentSelectedItem = episodeslist.get(position);
        currentSelectedItem.setPlanetSelected(true);
        PlanetModel previousSelectedItem = episodeslist.get(previousItem);
        previousSelectedItem.setPlanetSelected(false);
        
        // Notify the changes to the adapter
        
        notifyItemChanged(previousItem);
        notifyItemChanged(position);


        SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).apply ();


        // Here you should define `item` before triggering the interface callback.
        
         listener.onItemClick(item);
        
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

The click listener should not be in the `bind()` as this is called from `onBindViewHolder`, you are iterating many listeners while you should only need one, to fix this, you need to transfer that to the holder constructor:

So, change the `onBindViewHolder` to:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
    tv.setText(episodeslist.get(position));
    tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bg, 0, 0, 0);

   
    // setting the highlight color
    if (episodeslist.get(position).isPlanetSelected()) {
        vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        
    } else {
        vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

}
```

And change the `ViewHolder` to:

```
public class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected TextView text;
    public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                
            int position = getAdapterPosition();

            int previousItem = selectedPosition;
            selectedPosition = position;
            
            // Updating the selector boolean before notifying the changes to the adapter
            
            PlanetModel currentSelectedItem = episodeslist.get(position);
            currentSelectedItem.setPlanetSelected(true);
            PlanetModel previousSelectedItem = episodeslist.get(previousItem);
            previousSelectedItem.setPlanetSelected(false);
            
            // Notify the changes to the adapter
            
            notifyItemChanged(previousItem);
            notifyItemChanged(position);


            SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).apply ();


            // Here you should define `item` before triggering the interface callback.
            String item  = episodeslist.get(position);
            listener.onItemClick(item);
                
            }
        });
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , but `getBindingAdapterPosition` is not working , is it because I use java 1.7  `and recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'`

Comment: @cyberpunk then you should use `getAdapterPosition()` instead but you should migrate as `getAdapterPosition()` is deprecated now

Comment: `getAdapterPosition()` also not working , is there any other workaround for this beside migrating?

Comment: mmm.. there might be something else wrong.. Can you debug and log down the `position` value if it's the expected clicked item position, then there is issues with that.

Comment: Sir, I can confirm 100% the position is exactly the that I want, for example when I click episode 3 the position (index) is 2 , I checked this many times using break points, so I'm guessing something else is wrong

Comment: do you think it is because the fact that I use 2 interfaces to transfer the clicked position from adapter to activity , I mean like this, OnItemClickListener from adapter to the fragment where I applied the adapter then another interface from fragment to the activity?

Comment: @cyberpunk Please check the UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: Sir , I applied the update as you described , but I'm not getting the highlight color at all

Comment: @cyberpunk I got one more thing from the `onBindViewHolder` you are using the local variable, instead you should change the condition with the boolean from the pojo class .. Check updated answer (specifically the updated `onBindViewHolder()`)

Comment: with the update when I click on an item nothing happens sir

Comment: Sir , here is the [**source code**](https://mega.nz/file/xp0WlSRD#koMkFzXCSNINYMP4vb8VWVx4c88QEY_qczhkDeJ3j68) so that you understand better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234178/discussion-between-zain-and-cyberpunk).

Comment: Sir , I think I know what the problem is, each page or each episode of viewpager has its own instance of recyclerview, that is why this behavior happens

Comment: After applying the latest code , I still the same behavior, I think each page or each episode of viewpager has its own instance of recyclerview, that is why this behavior happens

Comment: sir are you there?

Comment: Thank you sir, have a great time

Comment: Sir, I found [**this on medium**](https://medium.com/android-news/dynamic-viewpager-indicator-with-recyclerview-items-in-android-388493272491), it is very similar to what I want to achieve ,  [**source code on github**](https://github.com/CodeBoy722/Dynamic_ViewPager_Indicator)